# how to add security header in jax-ws request

Tags: java, spring, cxf, jax-ws, cxf-client

I'm creating a jax-ws client with apache cxf.
I'm struggling with spring cotext configuration.
All I need is to add this header to my soap request:

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security  xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="usernametoken">
        <wsse:Username>login</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>        
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

I have three parameters: usernametoken, password, login.

```
    <jaxws:client id="***" name="***"
              endpointName="***"
              serviceName="***"
              address="***"
              serviceClass="***"
              username="***"
              password="***"
              xmlns:tns="***">
</jaxws:client>
```

the code above works and sends soap message, but without security header!
Could you give me some ideas how to add that header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this configuration

```
<jaxws:client   etc...>
      <jaxws:outInterceptors>     
       <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
          <constructor-arg>
              <map>
                  <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken"/>
                  <entry key="user" value="login"/>
                  <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText"/>
                  <entry key="passwordCallbackRef" value-ref="myPasswordCallback"/>
               </map>
           </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
      </jaxws:outInterceptors>
   </jaxws:client>

   <bean id="myPasswordCallback" class="client.ClientPasswordCallback"/>
```

And this class to manage the password

```
public class ClientPasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler {

    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, 
            UnsupportedCallbackException {
        WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];

        if ("login".equals(pc.getIdentifier())) {
            pc.setPassword("thepassword");
        } // else {...} - can add more users, access DB, etc.
    }
}
```

If you prefer Java code, also is possible

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();
Map<String,Object> outProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();
outProps.put("action", "UsernameToken");
outProps.put("user", "login");
outProps.put("passwordType","PasswordText");
ClientPasswordCallback c = new ClientPasswordCallback();
outProps.put("passwordCallbackRef",c);

WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
```

Comment: Hi, why do we have to check user ? Is this code for client-side? Looks like this code for server-side. I'm not configuring an endpoint, I just want to add a security header and send the soap request

Comment: This code is for client-side (see the jax-ws:client tag). An out-interceptor intercepts the output before it was sent to add the header. If you do not like spring config use the last java example. Maybe you found strange the way to provide the password, but it is the default for CXF

Comment: I am using Redhat fuse-karaf 7.10 with Java 11. This same setup now throws `javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted.` This used to work fine with Java 8 and  Redhat fuse-karaf 7.4.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the security header with a CXF interceptor.

So you basically need to define a new interceptor bean ([WSS4JOutInterceptor](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/ws/security/wss4j/WSS4JOutInterceptor.html) from cxf-security) and pass the correct key values as input to its constructor:

```
<bean id="fooSecurityOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
        [...]
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Note that this is documented at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html but you may want to look at the source code of org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandlerConstants for all the possible keys (in your case, look at USERNAME_TOKEN, PASSWORD_TYPE...) and inject your values to the corresponding keys in this bean.

Then, you simply assign this bean as an out interceptor to your jaxws-client bean.

```
<jaxws:client id="***" name="***" endpointName="***" serviceName="***" address="***" serviceClass="***" xmlns:tns="***">
    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="fooSecurityOutInterceptor" />
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>
</jaxws:client>
```

That should do the trick.
You can add a second out interceptor like [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/interceptor/LoggingOutInterceptor.html) to check that your header is added to tweak the keys / values a bit.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Well, I've found a class : UsernameTokenInterceptor it will resolve my problem. How could I add it in spring context?